# resizing winForm like an image

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to re-size a windows form in c# like resizing an image.

for example I want to re-size a windows form like these pictures: (1->2)

Before resizing:

[image: Main Form]

After resizing:

[image: Resized Form]

If there is an answer in WPF, please explain it...

Comment: Move to WPF. It will be fare more easier to do, as there are some controls that handle this requirement.

Comment: Just assign the form's Font property with a smaller font.

Comment: In WPF: 2 lines of XAML (Wrap everything in a `<Viewbox/>`). In dinosaur technologies: a horrible hell of "owner draw" and P/Invoke stuff.

Comment: There's nothing built-in to the WinForms subsystem to do that.  You'd have to somehow draw the form off-screen to a bitmap, scale it, then display the bitmap scaled.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15196213/187697

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Control.Scale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158413.aspx) method on Form.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using Anchor property? There's an option on anchoring the top, bottom, left and right.