# Height of dynamically added UserControl to TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, resize, tablelayout

I am writing an `winForm` app which will be something like `RSS` reader.

I have Form with 1 `Panel` and in this `panel` I have `TableLayoutPanel` and I am dynamically adding my `UserControls` into this `TableLayoutPanel` (because I don´t know how many `UserControls` there will be).

My `UserControl` represents 1 `RSS` article - it consists of 1 `TableLayoutPanel` with 4 rows (in every row is 1 `label`) - `Title, Date, Description and etchedLine.`

Everything seems OK but when I try to `resize` main `Form`, my `UserControls` don´t resize so when Description is too long part of article is missing.

I tried set `AutoSize` property to True and `Dock = Fill` for everything I could find but without success. It looks like my dynamically added `UserControl` has standard size and doesn't `resize` with main `Form`.

Here it is OK:
[image]

Here it is not OK (text and line is missing):
[image]

I would really appreciate any help you could can give me.

Comment: Hope it helps:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131779/resize-controls-with-form-resize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131779/resize-controls-with-form-resize)

Comment: thank you but still I have no idea what I am doing wrong :(

Comment: As an alternative, you can generate and html content based on the rss feed and show the generated html content in a web browser control.

Comment: That was my first choice but then I chose this one with tablelayoutpanels and userControls because I thought it would be easier ... well ...

Comment: I would replace the TableLayoutPanel with a FlowLayoutPanel both inside and outside the UCs. TLPs are not easy to handle dynamically..