# How can I keep vertical spacing of control objects equally proportional while the form height is being resized?

Tags: c#, winforms, spacing

I have a form that I'm allowing it to be resizable. On one of the panels of the form I have 4 lines of text boxes each equally spaced vertically by 40 pixels. When I resize the form's height by enlarging it, the vertical spacing between the text boxes do not increase equally. I would also like them to decrease equally when I decrease the form's height.

On the first text box I set the Anchor property to Top, Right.
Second and third text boxes I set the Anchor property to Right.
On the fourth text box I set the Anchor property to Bottom, Right.

This only equally enlarged the first and last vertical spacing and only moved the second and third text boxes up and down, but vertical still keeping the initial vertical space.

And I am NOT looking to resize the control. Only looking to reposition the control when the form itself resizes.

Comment: Use a [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resize Controls with Form Resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131779/resize-controls-with-form-resize)